# calloc in function parameter return value

Tags: calloc

My code runs fine on my computer and other test VMs I have, but on my customer's computer, the behavior is undefined. Sometimes, after pressing OK on the MessageBox in _tmain, the compiled exe uses 100% of the CPU and sometimes it bombs out.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

DWORD GetVS(TCHAR **sGetVS)
{
    DWORD dwSize = 1024;    
    *sGetVS = (TCHAR *) calloc(dwSize,sizeof(TCHAR));

    // Buffer for the environment variable value.
    TCHAR *sBuffEnv = (TCHAR *) calloc(4096+1,sizeof(TCHAR));   
    DWORD dwRet = GetEnvironmentVariable(L"VS90COMNTOOLS", sBuffEnv, 4096);
    if (dwRet)
    {
        StringCchCopy(*sGetVS,_tcslen(sBuffEnv)+1,sBuffEnv);
        MessageBox(0,sBuffEnv,*sGetVS,0);
        _tcslwr_s(*sGetVS,_tcslen(*sGetVS)+1);  // +1 is required for the null char
    }
    free(sBuffEnv);sBuffEnv=NULL;
    return 1;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR *sTemp = NULL;
    GetVS(&sTemp);
    MessageBox(0,sTemp,L"",0);
    free(sTemp);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried removing the last `free` and have even put a `sTemp=NULL;` after `free`, but the same problem is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two issues I see and they both deal with the length of the possible value of `"VS90COMNTOOLS"`.

First `GetEnvironmentVariable` is being used incorrectly. If the buffer passed in is not large enough to hold the environment variable value, the return value of `GetEnvironmentVariable` is the number of characters required to hold the value including the null terminator. If the function fails because the buffer is not large enough, the return value is not zero as your code assumes. You should see if the return value is 0 (for failure, e.g. not found) or if it is greater than the size of the buffer passed in (too small).

Second, `dwSize` is used to allocate 1024 characters for `sGetVS` where the buffer `sBuffEnv` is allocated 4097 characters. If the value returned in `sBuffEnv` is greater than 1024 characters, you will overflow the buffer allocated for `sGetVS` when doing `StringCchCopy` which will cause a nasty heap corruption causing your app to abort (or do any number of weird things).

### Update

If the environment variable is too large to fit in the supplied buffer, the return value from `GetEnvironmentVariable` is the size that is needed for the buffer to be able to hold the variable. In this case, the contents of `sBuffEnv` are undefined (could be untouched, could be truncated value with or without null terminator, contain garbage..., there are no guarantees what it may contain after the call). If this is the case you could be using bad data when you do the `StringCchCopy`.

Comment: Re: the GetEnvironmentVariable, the variable is a path, and the MAX_PATH is defined as 260, so 1024 will hold it, so sBuffEnv will never be > 1024 chars.

I was getting the value from passing a "0" to the API, and it made no difference on the client.

Comment: Certainly, if the variable indeed contains a valid path. Your code assumes that it does and does not take steps to ensure that it is correct. I could break this code very easily if I were the tester. Assuming the input is correct I do not see the problem in this portion of code.

Comment: Besides the testing of the correct size of the buffers, can you help at all regarding why the code is having problems after the MessageBox in the _tmain? As I mentioned, sometimes it uses 100% of the CPU and other times it just gives an general error/GPF.

Comment: Are you certain `"VS90COMNTOOLS"` exists and is defined correctly on the client's computer? Is this the actual code that is bombing or is this cut from a larger code base? What you describe really sounds like a memory corruption to me the causes of which I've laid out here.

Comment: Yes, it is defined on the client computer. Yes, this is the actual code that is bombing. The environment variable is this on the client's computer: VS90COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\

Comment: This is a tough one. You can add my machine to the list of machines where this code works fine!

Comment: I'm guessing from the path shown, the client machine is running a 32-bit version of VS on a 64-bit machine? Are you building the executable on the client machine or installing a binary built on your machine? Is the build targeting 32-bit or 64-bit? Is the build linking with the correct runtime libraries? I don't do a lot of cross compiling anymore so I'm just guessing about where to look for issues.